# .wlapp Android environment is not deploying on Worklight Server

Tags: android, oracle, deployment, ibm-mobilefirst, openjpa

We are developing an Banking MobileFirst application using MFP V7.1. We setup  development worklight box of WAS V8.5.5.5 Liberty profile ready for which we used Oracle DB as database. When I deploy the common environment .wlapp on development worklight box, it is deploying without any problem, but when I deploy android or iphone environment .wlapp I'm ending up with the following error in the MobileFirst Console

> Connection failure. Check the server log for details.

I checked for the detials in messages.log file on my development worklight server box, I'm seeing the following message

> [10/25/16 12:11:07:706 IST] 00009e14 SystemErr
>   R 587842010  WorklightManagementPU-oracle  INFO   [pool-4-thread-11]
>   openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions,
>   OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have
>   requested a lock on some data.

What I observer is: The size of common enviroment is 3MB and the size od android environment is 7MB. Is there any problem with the application(wlapp) size for deployment. I tried creating a HelloWorld mobilefirst application with common, android and iphone environment and deployed the wlapp of all the three evvironment on my development worklight box, it is deploying without any problem. Why my application android and iphone environment deployment not happening. 
Please find messages.log file logs:

> [10/25/16 12:11:07:534 IST] 00000117 om.worklight.applications.deployers.base.EnvironmentDeployer I FWLSE0274I: Environment common deployed to directory '/app/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/server1/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/75/data/temp/default_node/SMF_WebContainer/myAppworklight/myApp/widget-resources/myAppApp-common-a55269709850737f517f8daf9095668772993f56' . [project myAppworklight]
>   [10/25/16 12:11:07:662 IST] 00009e14 com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction              I Result: myAppworklight: server1///MyServerIP: Preparation to deploy 'myAppApp' finished
>   [10/25/16 12:11:07:681 IST] 00000117 com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl           I FWLSE0275I: Starting transaction with ID 324 for 'commit'.  [project myAppworklight]
>   [10/25/16 12:11:07:683 IST] 00009e14 com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction              I Result: myAppworklight: server1///MyServerIP: Commit
>   [10/25/16 12:11:07:683 IST] 00009e14 com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction              I myAppworklight: server1///MyServerIP: 2016-10-25T06:41:07.681Z: Application 'myAppApp' was updated
>   [10/25/16 12:11:07:706 IST] 00009e14 SystemErr                                                    R 587842010  WorklightManagementPU-oracle  INFO   [pool-4-thread-11] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.

Comment: What is the database software that you're using? MySQL? DB2? Oracle?

Comment: Hi Idan, We are using Oracle database

Comment: (1) I think the size shouldn't matter default blob size is 2 GB ----> http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefblob.html (2) The logs that you have pasted is normal message logs not related to functional error. Could you check for any other error in the logs. (3) When you upload the wlapp does it fail immediately ?.

Comment: Hi Vin, Thanks for your response. 1) I don't see any other log files oterthan messages.log and console.log and no any other error logs. If you know the path/location, can you please tell me where I can find any other  error logs on the Worklight Liberty profile. 2) I don't get the error immediatley on uploading the myApp-android.wlapp, it is taking some time apprroximately 55 to 60 seconds.

Comment: Hi Vin, Why I specified size is I create a sample hellowMobileFirst application with common, android and iphone environments and deployed successfully with out any errors. Even my application common environment "myApp-common.wlapp"(size 3.5MB) is deployed successfully on the worklight server without any errors.Only problem is when I try to deploy my applications android "myApp-android.wlapp"(6.7MB) or iphone "myApp-iphone.wlapp"(6.9MB) evironment I'm getting the error "Connectionfailure, please check the server log for details" in worklight console.Any solution will be greatly helpful.

Comment: 2)I also checked the ffdc logs also but there is no entry in the ffdc logs for today and I did not found any errors in ffdc logs. I'm unable to find any errors in console or messages log files also. I don't know where the error logs get logged other than messages console and ffdc logs, can you please specify the log file other than these three logs. 3) When I deploy my applications andoid (myApp-android.wlapp)  or iphone(myApp-iphone.wlapp) environmnet  immeditaley I'm not getting the error "Connection failure. Check the server log for details" after 50 to 60 seconds I'm getting the error

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't find any errors then might be related to slow network. May be some thing to do with the connection time out.

Check if you installed the below iFix:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI59605

Comment: Hi Vin, Thanks a lot for your response, the solution got worked, by increasing the Timeout for wlapp and adapter deployment on worklight server console and redeploying the worklightconsole war file, the issue got resolved. Thank you very much for your response and time.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add two best practises, the time out and MySQL packet size needs to be changed by default as part of the deployment to avoid this.